# RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.23) or chardet (2.3.0) doesn't match a supported version

Tags: python-2.7, json.net, python-requests, urllib3, chardet

I get this below error when i try to run cisco nxapi code.

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/**init**.py:91: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.23) or chardet (2.3.0) doesn't match a supported version!

RequestsDependencyWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NXAPI.py", line 31, in 
    response = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(payload), headers=myheaders,auth=(switchuser,switchpassword)).json()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 896, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/**init**.py", line 518, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Please let me know how do i get rid of this.